# Query jboss Envers log for one of several properties changed (or condition)

Tags: hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

I'm attempting to use Envers to query "significant" revisions, those that have one of several properties changed. Using AuditQuery's `add(AuditEntity.property("someproperty")` for each property creates an "`AND`" relationship where all the named properties must be changed for the revision to be pulled.

Is there a way to change this to a "`or`" relationship for these property modification flags?

`AuditQuery aq =` ... (create query and add the type and revision limits)

```
aq.add(AuditEntity.property("deleted").hasChanged())
            .add(AuditEntity.property("title").hasChanged())
            .add(AuditEntity.property("scopeOfWork").hasChanged())
            .add(AuditEntity.property("dueDate").hasChanged())
            .add(AuditEntity.property("estimatedHours").hasChanged())
            .add(AuditEntity.property("estimatedCost").hasChanged());
```

Answer (score 1):

As ussual, as soon as I ask the question, no matter how long I've worked on it, I come up with the answer.

For anyone else trying to figure this out:

```
 aq.add(AuditEntity.disjunction()
                .add(AuditEntity.property("title").hasChanged())
                .add(AuditEntity.property("scopeOfWork").hasChanged())
                .add(AuditEntity.property("dueDate").hasChanged())
                .add(AuditEntity.property("estimatedHours").hasChanged())
                .add(AuditEntity.property("estimatedCost").hasChanged()));
```

It just wasn't clear from the main Envers docs how to use disjunction or that it applied to AuditEntity.property criteria. It does and works as expected.